# Total number of unique symmetric random walk paths that return to the origin

Tags: recursion, random-walk

I'm solving the below quoted problem, and I was wondering if there's actually an analytical closed form solution?

> Suppose there are $n$ connected squares in a straight line. You start in the first square.
> You can move to the right, or to the left of your first square, provided that your next step is still within the straight line of squares (e.g., in the first step you can't move left, and can only move right because moving left would make you go off-grid).
> You traverse $m$ steps. How many unique paths are there such that you return to square 1?

I don't think there's an analytical closed form solution. I think you can define a recursion based on states, where the states are represented by the number of steps remaining and the square we're on.

Define $T(i, j)$ to be the number of unique paths to reach square $i$ from square 1 using $j$ steps. Our boundary condition is $T(1, 0) = 1$. We also know that $T(i, j) = 0$ if $i$ is odd (even) and $j$ is even (odd).

Our recursion is:
$$
T(i, j) = 
T(i + 1, j - 1) + T(i - 1, j - 1) 
$$

If any of the terms is out of bounds on the RHS, they just become zero. The recursion seems pretty simple, but is there a closed form solution for this?

Comment: Have you thought about viewing it as a graph?  If $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then then $T(i,j)$ is the $(i,1)$ entry of $A^j$.  I'm don't know how complicated this would be to work out.

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah, I'm basically viewing it as a graph / markov chain here. This appeared in a dynamic programming chapter of a book, so I'm not sure if there's a closed form solution, but there's been problems in the past where there's a nice looking closed form solution when I initially didn't think there'd be a nice closed form solution.

Comment: The simple recurrence here produces an answer in $O(nm)$ operations, whereas computing the $m$th power of the adjacency matrix needs $O(n^3\log m)$ operations (or $\sim O(n^{2.4}\log m)$ if you use a best-known matrix multiplication algorithm). That can be an advantage if $m\ggg n$.

Comment: @Troposphere Is the best-known matrix multiplication algo the one where you exponentiate matrices? (like how you do with fibonacci's)

Comment: @24n8: I'm assuming we compute the matrix power by repeated squaring in any case, but for the individual multiplication steps there are (quite complex) agorithms to multiply two $m\times m$ matrices faster than $\Omega(m^3)$. -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: It doesn't appear that there's a nice closed-form solution for the general case.  I computed the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix up through $n=9$ and although each of the matrices as $n$ distinct eigenvalues, I didn't see any pattern.  At $n=10$, sympy couldn't compute the eigenvalues.

Comment: @saulspatz: Out of curiosity, how many of the eigenvalues have magnitude $\ge 1$?

Comment: Here are the absolute values for $n=9$: $$0.6180339887498949\\ 1.618033988749895\\ 1.618033988749895\\ 0.6180339887498949\\ 1.1755705045849463\\ 1.902113032590307\\ 1.1755705045849463\\ 1.902113032590307\\ 0.0$$

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $m\leq 2n$, the paths you are looking for are equivalent to Dyck words. There are various well-known ways to prove that the number of Dyck words is given by the Catalan numbers. So in this case: $C_{m/2} = \frac{1}{m/2+1}\binom{m}{m/2}$, ($m$ should obviously be even).